# TreeViewItem - Use ControlTemplate and HierarchicalDataTemplate together

Tags: wpf, treeview, templates

I'm using HierarchicalDataTemplate in my TreeView, and I wanted to also overwrite the default template for the TreeViewItem so that when an item is selected, it only highlights the text, not including the icon next to it.

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
     <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                        <TreeViewItem Style="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}" Header="{Binding DisplayText}" />

      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>


            <TreeView.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemFocusVisual">
                    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Rectangle/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
                <Style x:Key="ExpandCollapseToggleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="19"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="13"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                <Border Width="19" Height="13" Background="Transparent">
                                    <Border Width="9" Height="9" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" BorderBrush="#FF7898B5" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1">
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset=".2"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFC0B7A6" Offset="1"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Border.Background>
                                        <Path x:Name="ExpandPath" Fill="Black" Margin="1,1,1,1" Data="M 0 2 L 0 3 L 2 3 L 2 5 L 3 5 L 3 3 L 5 3 L 5 2 L 3 2 L 3 0 L 2 0 L 2 2 Z"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="M 0 2 L 0 3 L 5 3 L 5 2 Z"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
                <Style x:Key="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1,0,0,0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItemFocusVisual}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}" ClickMode="Press" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1" >
                                        <Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="3,0" Source="{Binding Path=ImageSource}" />
                                        <Border x:Name="Bd" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Margin="0" Padding="0">
                                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" ContentSource="Header"/>
                                        </Border>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="false">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ItemsHost" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Expander" Value="Hidden"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger>
                                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                            <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                                    </MultiTrigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.Resources>
```

I couldn't find a way to use both the HierarchicalDataTemplate and ControlTemplate together so I can specify  the ItemsSource and also change parts of the control's behavior. When I do the above code, it won't select the treeviewitem at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of having the HierarchicalDataTemplate supply a TreeViewItem, you can supply a TextBlock.  The TreeView will automatically wrap the TextBlock in TreeViewItem containers.  Now you can use the ItemContainerStyle property of the TreeView to automatically apply the style to all of the automatically generated TreeViewItems.  The code below should give you the general idea (haven't fully checked it, so caveat coder):

```
<TreeView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}">
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
     <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayText}" />

      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>


            <TreeView.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemFocusVisual">
                    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Rectangle/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
                <Style x:Key="ExpandCollapseToggleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="19"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="13"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                <Border Width="19" Height="13" Background="Transparent">
                                    <Border Width="9" Height="9" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" BorderBrush="#FF7898B5" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1">
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset=".2"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFC0B7A6" Offset="1"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Border.Background>
                                        <Path x:Name="ExpandPath" Fill="Black" Margin="1,1,1,1" Data="M 0 2 L 0 3 L 2 3 L 2 5 L 3 5 L 3 3 L 5 3 L 5 2 L 3 2 L 3 0 L 2 0 L 2 2 Z"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="M 0 2 L 0 3 L 5 3 L 5 2 Z"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
                <Style x:Key="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1,0,0,0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItemFocusVisual}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}" ClickMode="Press" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1" >
                                        <Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="3,0" Source="{Binding Path=ImageSource}" />
                                        <Border x:Name="Bd" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Margin="0" Padding="0">
                                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" ContentSource="Header"/>
                                        </Border>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="false">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ItemsHost" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Expander" Value="Hidden"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger>
                                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                            <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                                    </MultiTrigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.Resources>

</TreeView>
```