# How to add node button to empty node-element

Tags: c#, wpf

All the elements in `TreeView` that contains child elements has a [picture/button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xeCA.png) which can be used to open that particular node.
Elements that do not contain child elements they do not have that picture/button.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding nodes}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nodes}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

How can I add a button to the empty nodes (those that does not contain child elements) to support the same functionality (to be able to open/close that node)?

Comment: Can you provide the sample code of your treeview?

Comment: Check out datatemplate and datatemplate selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expander button exists in each TreeViewButton. It's visibility depends on child elements - Expander is hidden if there is no childs. It is configured in TreeViewItem ControlTemplate ([see full example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2859662/1506454)):

```
<Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Expander" Value="Hidden"/>
</Trigger>
```

you can edit entire template and remove that trigger

... or override it individually for each TreeViewItem:

Add a Style for TreeViewItems in TreeView like this and handle Loaded event:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding nodes}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">

    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="FrameworkElement_OnLoaded"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nodes}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

</TreeView>
```

```
private void FrameworkElement_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tvi = (TreeViewItem)sender;
    var btn = tvi.Template.FindName("Expander", tvi) as UIElement;
    if (btn != null)
        btn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

when TreeViewItem is loaded, it is possible to find Expander button in visual tree, created from ControlTemplate. Assigning local value to `Visibility` overrides existing Trigger

[image: expander for empty nodes]

Comment: @QuintusFabiusMaximus, the only part which is conserned with how TreeView looks is View. with MVVM it will look exactly the same